# Crystal Reports: Page Header Appearing On Next Page When Previous Page Full

Tags: crystal-reports, report, subreport

So I've got a report which I'm using as a job traveler that contains subreports (Details h and l) and has a header (Page Header a) which updates accordingly depending on the subreport information. Everything works as it should when printing, unless a page is nearly full of 'Details h' subreport detail, in which case the next page is blank but displays the same 'Page Header a' from the previous page along with the Page Footer. The page after this continues correctly, unless of course the data fills the page again, in which case the aforementioned issue reoccurs.

If I adjust the size of the 'Group Footer #1'  to be as small as possible, I no longer have any blank pages in the middle of my report when printing, but I do have the aggravating issue of the repeating page header issue persisting as described above when the page is full. This means that if Page 1 contains 'Detail h' for Job A which nearly reaches the bottom of the page, the same Job A 'Page Header a' will be used on Page 2 under which the correct new 'Detail a' and 'Detail h' for Job B is displayed. The last page is always blank, displaying only 'Page Header a' and 'Page Footer' if the previous page is full - no matter which route I take.

The first issue is preferred since the heading matches the detail at least, despite having blank pages throughout, but I really need to eliminate the blank pages altogether. So what am I missing here?

I am using Crystal Reports 9 and this is my report layout:

```
ABBREVIATION LEGEND (Boxes Checked in Section Expert)
(Free-Form Placement is selected for every section)
(Suppress Blank Section is selected for every section)
H: Hide
S: Suppress
PABOP: Print at Bottom of Page
NPB: New Page Before
NPA: New Page After
KT: Keep Together

TRAVELER DESIGN
SECTIONS:        BOXES CHECKED:        SUBREPORTS:
Report Header    H/S/NPB
Page Header      KT
  Page Header a  KT
  Page Header b  S/KT
Group Header #1  H/S
Details          KT
  Details a      KT
  Details b      S
  Details c      S
  Details d      S
  Details e      S
  Details f      S
  Details g      S
  Details h      KT                    Traveler Routing Subreport
  Details i      S
  Details j      S
  Details k      S
  Details l      KT                    Traveler Component Subreport
  Details m      S
Group Footer #1  NPA/KT
Page Footer      PABOP/NPA/KT
Report Footer    H/S


TRAVELER ROUTING SUBREPORT:
SECTIONS:        BOXES CHECKED:
Report Header    H/S
Group Header #1  KT
Group Header #2  H/S
Details          
  Details a      KT
  Details b      S
Group Footer #2  H/S
Group Footer #1  H/S
Report Footer    H/S


TRAVELER COMPONENT SUBREPORT:
SECTIONS:        BOXES CHECKED:
Report Header    H/S
Group Header #1  KT
Details          KT
Group Footer #1  H/S
Report Footer    H/S
```

Comment: Inside your subreport, try supressing unused sections (e.g. sub report ReportFooter, PageFooter.) If that doesn't work - I think you will need to provide additional information. There are a lot of different variables at play here (e.g. is the subreport placed in the main report Details section or Group Footer, etc -or- is the subreport or any of its sections set to "Keep Together", -or- when you view the Section Expert of the subreport, then click on the "paging" tab, make sure "New Page After / End Of Section" is not selected)

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, I've added my layout information to my original post. All unused sections are suppressed and you can now see which sections are set to Keep Together. The only section which is set to New Page After is the Group Footer #1 on the Traveler Design as well as the Report Footer, but the latter is ghosted so I don't seem to have any control over that one. I'm eagerly waiting to see if this helps in pinpointing my issue. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

> Regarding: "The last page is always blank if it is full no matter
>   which route I take."

Go to Section Expert for the Main Report's Group 1 Footer. Where you see the checked checkbox for New Page After, click the little pencil icon and enter the following formula: **NOT OnLastRecord**

> Regarding the white spacing following large subreport

Try this: when in the Main Report designer, right-mouse click on the subreport and select Format Object, then uncheck "Keep Object Together"

Comment: Thanks again, most unfortunately though, both those things do not appear to make any difference whatsoever.

Comment: Is there anything else that could possibly be causing this?

Comment: the field inside the subreport might be the problem, try forcing that description field to not grow to see what happens. You might have that field fill with a lot of blank spaces on your data source. If you suppress the subreport, does the same thing happen?

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestion. Whether I disable the 'Can Grow' option via the 'Format Subreport' option on the Traveler Routing Subreport or I suppress 'Details h', I get the same result both times - 1 empty page with the correct heading and 'Details a' on each page of the report. What I can't figure out is why 'Details a' seems to know when the page should be blank, but 'Page Header a' doesn't - see the second paragraph in my original post above.